# Как применить регулярное выражение к web-странице?

Tags: javascript, c#, регулярные-выражения, .net, awesomium

Есть проект на .net, который написан на с#.
В контроле awesomium отображается web-страница . Нужно показать пользователю, как выглядит его регулярное выражение на странице. Например, подсветить все ссылки вида:

```
<a href="(?<link>.*?)">(?<title>.*?)</a>
```

Под "подсветить" понимается просто добавление какого-нибудь стиля `<div style="background-color: red"/>`

Мне на ум приходит два решения:

1. Выполнить JS скрипт.
2. Сохранить локальную копию веб-страницы и с ней уже работать.

Отсюда проблемы:

1. Регулярные выражения пишутся на применимом к .net синтаксисе. Как оказалось, в js есть некоторые отличия, а также есть элементы, которые вообще отсутствуют (проименованные группы). Даже если попробовать заменить несовместимые элементы, то через regexp сложные регулярные выражения так выполнить и не удалось.
2. Здесь все просто: полная совместимость, находит все совпадения и помечает. Но вот сохраненная страница (если содержимое генерируется автоматичеси) отличается от оригинала, т.е. могут отсутствовать изображения или вообще все стили css. Думал сначала сохранять страницу в какой-нибудь mht архив, но вот chromium (лежит в основе awesomium) отказывается их потом отображать.
   Как бы мне решить такую проблему? Может вам известны проекты, которые смогут правильно скачать всю web-страницу локально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня (в другой ситуации — хостинг OLE-компонента [`WebBrowser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), который представляет собой окошко IE) сработала такая идея: в корневой namespace js добавляется кастомный объект, который переправляет вызовы host-приложению.

В вашей ситуации, вы по идее можете проксировать запросы с регулярками в главное приложение. Вопрос лишь в том, позволяет ли ваш контрол awesomium такое.

---

Для обыкновенного, стокового [`WebBrowser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) проблема решается так: в свойство [`ObjectForScripting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx) прописывается ваш объект, который будет доступен из js как `window.external`.

---

В общем, я покопался в документации (которая у Awesomium не очень).

[Рекомендуемый новый метод](http://wiki.awesomium.net/changelogs/whats-new-1-7-5.html) связи js с программой — использование метода `OSMJIF.sendmessage` (документация [тут](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/T_global_OSMJIF.htm) и [тут](http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/6048/how-to-create-and-handle-javascriptmessage.html)):

```
var request = { pattern: '^regex$' };
var res = OSMJIF.sendMessage('execRegex', request);
```

В коде обработчик должен выглядеть как-то так ([[1]](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/E_Awesomium_Core_IWebView_JavascriptMessage.htm), [[2]](http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/6048/how-to-create-and-handle-javascriptmessage.html)):

```
// судя по всему, в webView.DocumentReady
webView.JavascriptMessage += OnJavascriptMessage;

void OnJavascriptMessage(object sender, JavascriptMessageEventArgs args)
{
    switch (args.Message)
    {
    case "execRegex":
        var arg = (JSObject)args.Arguments[0];
        // выполняем...
        // если нужно передать результат, то:
        args.Result = <результат в виде JSObject>;
        break;
    }
}
```

Этот метод работает начиная с версии 1.7.5.

Более старый и неудобный метод, через `CreateGlobalJavascriptObject`, описан [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13382677/276994).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Может я вас не до конца понял, но ведь это все равно не решает совместимости js регулярных выражений и .net. А у меня на вход как раз поступают регулярки .net.

Comment: @SergeyHoroshev: Почему же, должно решать. Через описанный механизм вы можете вызвать .NET-код из javascript. Таким образом, работу с регулярными выражениями вы можете делегировать .NET-коду. То есть ваш js-код вовсе не должен заниматься регулярками.

Comment: Так, теперь понял. Я на самом деле начала копать в сторону рекурсивного обхода и получения веб-страницы. То есть хочу прилепить к приложению какой-нибудь httrack и далее уже работать с локальной копией. Если эта идея не пройдет, то попробую взаимодействовать через OSMJIF. В теории все должно получиться. Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: @SergeyHoroshev: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можете добавлять в `<head>` изменённой локальной страницы тег:

```
<base href="http://example.com/original-path/">
```

тогда относительные пути будут работать корректно.

Способы запустить .NET-овые регулярные выражения под JS мне неизвестны.